# Convert data from bluetooth device to readable string

Tags: swift, core-bluetooth

I get a series of data from a bluetooth device, the data comes in bytes and since I'm beginner, I don't know how to make it a readable string

```
public func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
  let value: Data = characteristic.value!


  if let str = String(data: value, encoding: .utf8) {
     print(str)
  }
```

}

here in the console, I have

```
p characteristic.value
(Data?) $R0 = 182 bytes
```

with `String(data: value, encoding: .utf8)` I get something like that:

```
pGrIrIpGsIqGoFoEoEoEoEoEpEpEoCoCpCqEqEqEqEqEqEpCpGpGpFpGoFoEnEnEnEnEpFpFpFpFpFpFpFqFpFpFnDm
```

Could anyone help me how to make it readable?

Comment: What data are you getting; what does it represent? What code are you using to get it?

Comment: Do you have any idea of what it is? a String (even if in a JSON), an image, a video…
Along with the code asked from undescore_d would be usefull to know from what type of device you are receiving it (car Bluetooth, a camera, air pods, a laptop….)

Comment: It's a heart rate monitor device, I should get a raw data, but I don't know what is the exact structure

Comment: I imagine it's a stream of 'raw' numbers, not a string of characters representing numbers. My guess is there are 2 bytes per update, and since the subject's heart rate presumably doesn't need 2 bytes (is not over 255 bpm)... probably one of those bytes represents some other measurement (does it measure anything else?) or a status code of some kind. But really, without knowing what specific device model it is, this question still can't be answered without guessing. Even if the model was known, it might not have docs available for using it without an official driver. If it does, search for them.

Comment: What is the characteristic UUID you're using?

Comment: Also, what's the service UUID? (Just for completeness; we don't really need that as much as the characteristic.) I'm expecting something like service 0x180D, and probably characteristic 0x2A37.

Comment: Hmm…this is actually a little weird. I'm thinking this may not be the Heart Rate Service; we'll definitely need to know the service UUID and characteristic UUID. 182 bytes is pretty long for any of the standard service formats. Also, the string you've printed is only 91 bytes which is very suspiciously half the expected length.

Comment: It's not exactly a heart rate monitor, this is custom health device and I don't know its service ID. the ones who worked on the device already left the company, just want to know, when it's 182 bytes, how I can convert to string, it may be a string or int